# Blazor / Blazor Hybrid Input Issue on Mobile Devices

Tags: input, mobile, keyboard, blazor, maui

I am trying to solve this problem already for a month. I have an blazor web app app and also an blazor maui and when the input get focus on mobile at least for android  ,keyboard pop up but its cover / hide the input leading to a very poor user experience cuz the users are not able to see what they are typing. I did everything to fix it but I failed. I tried to add bottom padding or so but how can I know the device virtuall Keyboard height. If you guys have any Suggestions .
Thx a lot in advice

I tried with fixed position or adding padding but nothing worked

Comment: How can we give suggestions without knowing how your current code and page looks like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you can't get access to the `input` element when it is focused at the bottom of the page.

To fix it, you can try to set the `Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust` attached property to `Pan`.For more details, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/platform-specifics/soft-keyboard-input-mode?view=net-maui-7.0.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?> 
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp" 
                
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Pan"

             x:Class="MauiApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Compared with `Maui`,you can try to add a transparent frame to the bottom of the page which is the same height as the keyboard. Ugly but it works. For more details, you can refer to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13380.